# Python keeps returning an assertion error but I can’t tell where I went wrong

Tags: python

The question: Write a function count_unique_lines which takes as input an open file object file that supports reading and returns the number of distinct lines of file. For instance, if names.txt consists of the following lines
ALICE
BOB
CAESAR
BOB
and file has been obtained using open('names.txt'), then count_unique_lines(file) should evaluate to 3.
You may assume that the final character of each line is the newline character '\n'. Do not attempt to use the function open or call the close method of file.

My code:

```
def count_unique_lines(file):

    count = 0
    D= {}
    for line in file:
        if line in D: 
            continue 
    D[line] = True 
    count += 1
    return count
```

I keep getting an error but can’t figure out where I went wrong :(

Comment: Is that really a `Continue` with a capital `C` ? Also please indent the code properly

Comment: No, it’s not a capital C in my actual code. It capitalised it here, I didn’t notice.

Comment: Not sure, if it is indented properly still:/ Also, what is the error. Please paste the traceback with the question

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function with just mere 2 lines of code :)

 
lets say you have a file called **pie.txt**
which contains following lines 

`raspberry
choco
mango
keylime
potatoe
strudel
raspberry
mango`


Then you can write a method like this :

`def count_unique_lines(file):
    lines = {line.strip() for line in open(file) }
    return len(lines)`


which when you fire up, will return this:


`count_unique_lines('pie.txt')
6`